# How to send code from Sublime3 to evernote?

Tags: evernote

I've installed the package control "evernote plugin"and view in browser for Sublime3. When I passed the code to evernote, Sublime3 come out an alert as follows.

Evernote complained:

The contents of the note are not valid.
The inline HTML tag 'iostream' is not allowed in Evernote notes.

Retry?

My code is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  // declaring variables:
  int a, b;
  int result;

  // process:
  a = 5;
  b = 2;
  a = a + 1;
  result = a - b;

  // print out the result:
  cout << result;

  // terminate the program:
  return 0;
}
```

How can I cope with it?

Comment: Evernote probably thinks `<iostream>` in `#include <iostream>` is HTML. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Are you using the Sublime Text 3 port of the Evernote plugin? https://github.com/timlockridge/SublimeEvernote

Comment: I used this one - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Evernote.

Comment: I just want to make a copy of my code snippet to Evernote with some programming style. @ColonelThirtyTwo

Answer (score 1):

From the sublime-evernote package wiki:

#### Raw HTML

Take extra care in not using prohibited elements (see [here](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php)).
Evernote will complain if you use unsupported elements (such as `<style>`) or unsupported attributes (such as `class` or `id`).
If you wish to have the code within a raw html block interpreted as Markdown, specify a `markdown="1"` attribute for the outermost element:

```
<div markdown="1">
**Note**:

This is important!
</div>
```

Source: https://github.com/bordaigorl/sublime-evernote/wiki/Supported-Markdown#raw-html

Answer (score 0):

-- update--
You can deal with this problem by reinstall the sublime-evernot.I have tried, and it works well!

clone this repository with

$ git clone --recursive http://github.com/bordaigorl/sublime-evernote.git
in

- Windows: %APPDATA%/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/
- OSX: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/
- Linux: ~/.Sublime Text 3/Packages/

https://github.com/timlockridge/SublimeEvernote

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
&lt;iostream&gt;
```

Otherwise it will be interpreted by Markdown as literal HTML (and passed as such to Evernote)

Answer (score 0):

sublime-evernote supports [Fenced Code Blocks of GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/) as mentioned in [its wiki](https://github.com/bordaigorl/sublime-evernote/wiki/Supported-Markdown#fenced-code-blocks). Quoting the wiki:

> Fenced code blocks GitHub style are supported. If a language is specified, pygments is used to highlight the code.

So the correct way to send code is to include it within a block of triple backticks. Quoting the Github help link for fenced code blocks:

> You can create fenced code blocks by placing triple backticks ``` before and after the code block. We recommend placing a blank line before and after code blocks to make the raw formatting easier to read.
>
> You can add an optional language identifier to enable syntax highlighting in your fenced code block.
>
> We use [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) to perform language detection and syntax highlighting. You can find out which keywords are valid in the [languages YAML file](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml).

As mentioned above, you can also specify the language after the backticks. For example, for your code, you need to enclose it within:

```c++

```

After enclosing it like this, send it to evernote, and it will appear with proper syntax highlighting.